# VBA Date format

Tags: vba, excel, date

I need to filter a column that contain dates. I need to get all rows where the date is between the `current date` and the `current date + 15 days`

This is my VBA code to do that:

```
    Dim seuilDate As Date, currentDate As Date
    seuilDate = DateAdd("d", 15, Date)
    currentDate = Date

    MsgBox "Date seuil :" & seuilDate & "  Current Date:" & currentDate


    With Workbooks("macro1.xlsm").Worksheets("Feuil1")
        If .FilterMode Then .ShowAllData
        '.range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=3, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & currentDate, Criteria2:="<" & seuilDate, Operator:=xlAnd
    End With
```

this is what shows the MessageBox:

[image]

And this is what I want exactly,

but in the excel file this what I get:

[image]

the day and the month fields are inversed in the `CurrentDate+15` variable.

Any idea how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the date values to Doubles when applying them to the autofilter:

```
   .range("C:C").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & CDbl(currentDate), Criteria2:="<" & CDbl(seuilDate), Operator:=xlAnd
```

as VBA is very US-centric.